# How to organize Rails routes to divide content by cities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, seo, routes

I have a restaurants directory Rails app in which I need to categorize the content (restaurant description pages) by cities. The cities are stored in the database. The questions that I have:

1. What is the Rails way of doing this? Is it best to add a scope in routes as for ex. the language locale? For ex.: example.com/en/new-york/restaurants...
2. Is it better to translate, transliterate or leave the city names as-is provided that the content is targeted for the locals. For ex.: example.com/moscow vs example.com/moskva vs example.com/москва in terms of "Rails-wayness" and SEO friendliness?
3. In terms of SEO, is it better to use subdomains (new-york.example.com) or subdirectories (example.com/new-york).

I would appreciate if you could share your experience about this matter!

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably don't want the locale/language to be embedded in the URL.
2. For SEO purposes you probably want to pick one version and go with it all the time.  That way you're aggregating all of your "link juice" to one URL.  Some search engines will penalize you for having the same content at multiple URLs.
3. This is a good question, and I'm not entirely sure.  I'd be kind of surprised if either one makes a huge difference.  (It wouldn't be the first time I've been surprised...)